# Alphabetically sort using an insertion sort algorithm c#

Tags: c#, sorting, insertion-sort

I've been searching the internet and books but have had no luck so was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I basically need to sort objects by their name statement alphabetically using an insertion sort rather than the built in methods. I have tried using an Array and List but can't seem to get it to work. How would you go about doing it?

I have a class of Player, latest attempt filled with list objects:

```
    public static List<Player> user = new List<Player>(); 
    private string name; //Read and Write
    private int score; //Read and Write
    private double health; //Read and Write
    private int level;  //Read and Write
    public string[] inventory = new string[30];

    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }
    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setScore(int newScore)
    {
        score = newScore;
    }
    public int getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }
    public void setHealth(double newHealth)
    {
        health = newHealth;
    }
    public double getHealth()
    {
        return health;
    }
    public void setLevel(int newLevel)
    {
        level = newLevel;
    }
    public int getLevel()
    {
        return level;
    }

    public static void Saved_Player()
    {
        user.Add(new Player() { name = "Timid Bob", health = 63, level = 6, score = 2000, });
        user[0].inventory[0] = "Steel Sword";
        user[0].inventory[1] = "1mm MAW";
        user[0].inventory[2] = "Short Bow";
        user[0].inventory[0] = "Grenade";

        user.Add(new Player() {name = "Killer Bob", health = 82, level = 2, score = 1050000, });
        user[1].inventory[0] = "Glass Sword";
        user[1].inventory[1] = "250mm MAW";
        user[1].inventory[2] = "Elephant Bow";
        user[1].inventory[3] = "Rock";
```

etc... upto 6 user objects

To sort it I'm trying to use the following code in another class Form1:

//sudo code

```
          for(int i = 0; i < Player.user.Count; i++)
          {

            while (i index is higher than i+1 index)
            {
                swap i index with i+1 index
            }

          }
```

Hope that is right :/

I think I understand how PublicJoe's has done it but how do you get and set the index of an object? Thanks for looking.

Comment: homework?  What isn't working?  Post your code.

Comment: http://www.publicjoe.f9.co.uk/csharp/sort00.html

Comment: If you edit your question to include your best attempt so far, and explain why you think it doesn't work, you'll get some help with it.

Comment: If you're going for insertion sort then that's not it. Insertion sort means that for every new player, you will walk your user-list, compare the new player with the existing ones, find the correct **insertion point** and insert the player there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are bad for inserting into.  if you think back to your classes, you might find a data structure that works better for inserting.

In an insertion sort, you take an item of your unsorted list, and then put it in the correct spot of the other list.

What you seem to be trying to do, appears to be some sort selection sort.

I think there's a problem with the 4 lines where you swap your values

```
                object temp;
                object = Player.user[Second];
                Player.user[first] = Player.user[Second];
                Player.user[(temp - 1)] = Player.user[Second];
```

I'd have a second look at that if i were you.

Comment: Perhaps use?:

Temp object
Second object index = temp
Second object index = first object index
temp - 1 = Second object index

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a list, you can simply do this:

```
public void InsertionSort(Player newUser)
{
    var index = users.FindLastIndex(u => u.Name <= newUser.Name);
    users.Insert(index, newUser);
}
```